# Paho CPP - compile as a static executable

Tags: c++, g++, paho, static-compilation, pahocpp

Is it possible to compile Paho CPP as a static executable? If so - how?

Here is an example of the compilation statement for one of the examples:

```
g++ -DOPENSSL -I.. -I/usr/local/include -D_NDEBUG -Wall -std=c++11 -O2 -o data_publish data_publish.cpp -L../../lib -L/usr/local/lib -lpaho-mqttpp3 -lpaho-mqtt3a
```

How do I compile this as a static executable?

Answer (score 0):

[Build Paho with static libraries.](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp)

And then link it with `-static` command line switch. E.g. `g++ ... -static -lpaho-mqttpp3 -lpaho-mqtt3a`.